# Why SimpleBeanEditorDriver returns null values

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a SimpleBeanEditorDriver to edit my account bean but i always get null values when i edit and call flush(). i checked everything, Google documentations, stackoverflow, google groups but didn't find any problem like. did i miss something ?

here is my View

```
public class AccountCreatorViewImpl extends Composite {


  interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Account, AccountEditor> {
  }

  interface AccountCreatorViewImplUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, AccountCreatorViewImpl> {
  }


  Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);

  private static AccountCreatorViewImplUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(AccountCreatorViewImplUiBinder.class);


  private AccountCreatorPresenter presenter;


  @UiField
  AccountEditor accountEditor;

  @UiField
  Button create;

  public AccountCreatorViewImpl() {

    HTMLPanel rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

    initWidget(rootElement);

    Account account = new Account();

    driver.initialize(accountEditor);


    driver.edit(account);


  }

  @UiHandler("create")
  public void onCreate(ClickEvent event) {


    Account editedAccount = driver.flush();
    if (driver.hasErrors()) {

      Window.alert("Has errors! ->"+driver.getErrors().toString());
    }

    Window.alert(editedAccount.getEmail() + "/" + editedAccount.getPassword());

//    presenter.create(editedAccount);
  }


}
```

and here is my simple editor

```
public class AccountEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Account> {


  interface AccountEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, AccountEditor> {
  }

  private static AccountEditorUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(AccountEditorUiBinder.class);

  @UiField
  TextBox email;

  @UiField
  PasswordTextBox password;

  public AccountEditor() {

    HTMLPanel rootElement = ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

    initWidget(rootElement);


  }

}
```

and this is my Account class 
Account

```
public class Account implements Serializable {


  private String email;

  private String password;

  public Account(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Account() {

  }

  public Account(String email, String password) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }


  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
}
```

i also have the same problem with another editor in my app. actually neither one works. when i press save or create i get null values of the entity.

Comment: please show your Account class. Does it have the necessary getters and setters ?

Comment: this is my Account
public class Account implements Serializable {


  private String email;

  private String password;

  public Account(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Account() {

  }

  public Account(String email, String password) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }


  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

Try adding setEmail() and setPassword() methods to your account class